# Capacity for Dictionary in protobuf-net deserilization

Tags: protobuf-net

I have many `Dictionary` instances, deserilized from file by protobuf-net.

The `Count` of `Dictionary` is variable for each of them.
Some may get 10 items,  but other may get 10000000 items.

When protobuf-net deserilizes the `Dictionary`, is it possible first detecting the total size of current dictionary, then call the `Dictionary` contructor with appropriate `Capacity`  parameter according to the size of the dictionary;  and finally fill the `Dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

The underlying protobuf format that protobuf-net works to *does not declare* the number of incoming elements; in fact, for the root object, it doesn't even declare the length of the root object. So no, this is simply not possible, short of populating the data into a list or similar *first*, and then copying it *again* into the final right-sized dictionary.

Comment: I think I must be facing this problem trying to (de)serialize an in-memory lookup table ~ 0.7GB, which is basically a list of dictionaries (100s to 1000s entries each). Serialization is fast < 10s, but deserialization is extreme ~ 1hr. I'm guessing because it's spending all its time re-sizing dictionaries.